# Some Norms on $V=P_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$V=P_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of all polynomials with degree $\le n$. I need to know Which of the followings are norms on $V.$

$\forall p\in V$

1.$\|p\|^2=|p(1)|^2+\dots+|p(n+1)|^2$

2.$\|p\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|p(t)|$

3.$\|p\|=\int_{0}^{1}|p(t)|dt$

4.$\|p\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|p'(t)|$

for the $1$, $\|p\|=0\Rightarrow p\equiv 0$, also $\|\lambda p\|=|\lambda|\|p\|$,but I think $\|p+q\|\le \|p\|+\|q\|$ doesn't hold here, but I am not sure about the proof.

$2$ is our wellknown sup norm so it indeed a norm on $V$

$3$ is also a norm I am sure.

I can not say about $4$. 
Thanks for  correcting me

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1. is going to be a norm, but don't quote me on that. I haven't had a chance to work it out, yet. I doubt 4 will be, since differentiation wreaks havoc on order.

Comment: Got to ask you what we ask newbies: what have you tried? There are a few norm axioms; you will need to verify these candidates against them and see where they fail or not. At least one is not a norm. It's a good exercise

Comment: @SimonS instead of $2$ if the power is $n$ will it be a norm?

Comment: With (4) $\|1\|=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=c$, $c$ is a non-zero constant. Degree of $p$ is $0$ and $p\neq 0$ but $\|p\|=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|p'(x)|=0$ so 4 is not a norm.

EDIT: Thanks for warnings. Degree of $p$ is $n+1$ so it is not in $P_n(\mathbb R)$. If $p=0$ then trivially $\|p\|=0$. If $\|p\|=0$ then $|p(1)|=|p(2)|=\cdots=|p(n+1)|=0$ so the polynomial $p$ has roots at the points $1,2,\ldots,n+1$. This is impossible because $\deg(p)\le n$ so $p$ must be $0$. Absolute homogeneity of the function in (1) can be seen easily and the triangle inequality of (1) can be shown using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Thus the function in (1) is a norm.

Comment: Because $p(1)=p(2)=\cdots=p(n+1)=0$

Comment: Extremely sorry, I made a mistake, took $(x-(n-1))$ instead of $(x-n-1)=(x-(n+1))$.

Comment: But then the degree of $p(x)$ is $n+1$ hence $p(x)\notin P_n(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: You cannot use this example.

Comment: @ MBYagbasan : Please remove the first two lines, it is not true.

Comment: thanks for warnings @supremum.

Comment: Exactly.. I was trying to give that proof(using Minkowski's inequality).